# ¿Cómo aplicar la función applymap() a un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, map

Mi problema es el siguiente: intento aplicar una función a todo un dataframe surgiéndome el siguiente error:

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def getAcumuladoPuntos(self, resultados):
    puntos_resultados = resultados.applymap(self, self.getPuntos(resultados) ,type = 'string').head()

    for i in range(2, 39):
        puntos_resultados[i-1] += puntos_resultados[i]

    puntos_resultados.insert(column=0, loc=0, value=[0 * i for i in range(20)])
    return puntos_resultados

def getPuntos(self, resultado):
    if (resultado == 'V').any():
        return 3
    elif (resultado == 'E').bool():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

La finalidad de esto es aplicar al Dataframe de resultados(V=Victoria, E=Empate, D=Derrota) una función que me reemplace estos valores por sus debidos puntos.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Para relacionar la puntuación según el valor de la columna 'resultado' utilizaremos la función **map()** de la siguiente forma:

```
 # df es el dataframe 
 df['puntos']=df['resultado'].map({'V': 3,'E': 1, 'D': 0})
```

La columna 'puntos' contendrá el valor numérico que le corresponda según la columna 'resultado'. Utiliza la columna 'puntos' para realizar las operaciones que requieras.